Computing Haar measure of matrices sampled from SO(n)
I am looking to sample uniform matrices from SO(n).
I know that uniform matrices can be sampled from O(n) by taking the QR decomposition of Gaussian random square matrices and adjusting the sign of the diagonal values (e.g. as found here and in references therein). The uniformity of these matrices can then be tested by assessing the angle and spread of the eigenvalues of the matrices obtained (full code here):
[e.g.
import numpy as np
# to calculate Haar measure for a given matrix `input`
B,_ = np.linalg.eig(input)
evals = np.sort(np.angle(B))
seps = B.shape[0] / (2*np.pi) * np.diff(evals,axis=0) 

]
I note that the distribution of eigenvalues is approximately uniform in the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$ - except with many matrices having eigenvalues of $\pm1$ - is this expected?
Is it possible to uniformly sample from SO(n) by taking matrices sampled from O(n) and forcing the determinant to be +1?
(e.g. sample a matrix from O(n); then, if the determinant is -1, simply multiply the first column by -1).
If so, what is the equivalent Haar measure for this group?
Using the same computation as above changes the distribution of the eigenvalues significantly:

Given that eigenvalues of a  should occur in $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ complex conjugate pairs (with potentially one eigenvalue of +1, if n is odd), one possible alternative is to define the Haar measure using the argument of the eigenvalues in the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor})$. This does indeed create a uniform spread but I am not sure about the correctness of this approach.

crossposted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4892310/87355

It's probably better to sample matrices in $SO(n)$ by using the short exact sequence $SO(n-1)\to SO(n)\to S^n$, where points on $S^n$ are are normalized samples of a vector of random Gaussians. You need fewer random numbers this way, although you still need to perform some matrix multiplications.

BTW, you could sample from a density where eigenvalues are uniform on complex circle by sampling 2D rotations uniformly and using Jordan Normal form -- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/306257/217

Indeed, the distribution function of the eigenphases of a random matrix in $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ has a peak at 0 and at $\pm\pi$. It only becomes uniform for large $n$. The joint distribution function for $n=2m$ even is given by (Girko, 1985)
$$p(\theta_1, \cdots, \theta_m) = C \prod_{1 \leq k < j \leq m} (\cos\theta_k - \cos\theta_j)^2~.$$
As a simple example, for $n=4$ this gives upon integration over $\theta_2$ at fixed $\theta_1$ the density profile
$$p(\theta)=\frac{\cos 2 \theta+2}{4 \pi }.$$
If you sample from $O(n)$, you can either discard the matrices with determinant $-1$, or multiply the first column by $-1$.

By way of illustration, this is the density profile for $n=100$ (computed by averaging over 500 random matrices), when the peaks at $0$ and $\pm\pi$ have become very small.

The reason why the Haar measure for SO$(n)$ does not give a rotationally invariant density of eigenvalues on the unit circle is that the eigenvalues must come in complex conjugate pairs $e^{\pm i\theta}$. This constraint is not rotationally invariant.

What does it mean to be uniform (for large n) but also have peaks at 0 and $\pm \pi$? Does it mean that for large n, it would be uniform over the interval $(0,\pi)$ with peaks just at the end points?

It just means that the height of the peaks becomes smaller and smaller as n becomes larger and larger.

Is there a conceptual exploration for the occurrences of these peaks?

@LSpice --- one way  you might form an intuition goes like this: the eigenphases $\theta_m$ are confined to the interval $(0,\pi)$. They repel each other, so they want to spread out, and as they spread out they are pushed towards the "walls" at 0 and $\pi$.

How did you derive the formulae for the joint probability (and the example marginal probability)?

There's an asymmetry because members of O(n) include rotation with random angle and flips with random axis, for small $n$, the fraction of flips is large, which create peaks at $-1$ and $1$ peaks. Restricting to $SO(n)$ removes the peaks at $-1$, and $1$ remaining  density follows cosine formula from Girko

negateFirstRow[A_] := {-A[[1, All]]}~Join~A[[2 ;;, All]];
sampleO[n_] := RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[n]];
sampleSO[n_] := 
  With[{mat = sampleO@n}, If[Det[mat] > 0, mat, negateFirstRow@mat]];

n = 4;
numSamples = 100000;
label = StringForm["Eigenvalues of O(``)", n];
angles = Arg /@ Flatten[Table[Eigenvalues@sampleO@n, {numSamples}]];
Histogram[angles, Automatic, PDF, PlotLabel -> label, 
 AxesLabel -> {"arg", "density"}]

label = StringForm["Eigenvalues of SO(``)", n];
angles = Arg /@ Flatten[Table[Eigenvalues@sampleSO@n, {numSamples}]];
observedPlot = 
  Histogram[angles, {Pi/15}, PDF, PlotLabel -> label, 
   AxesLabel -> {"arg", "density"}];
predictedPlot = 
  Plot[(Cos[2 t] + 2)/(4 Pi), {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 3/(4 Pi)}, 
   PlotLegends -> {TraditionalForm[(Cos[2 t] + 2)/(4 Pi)]}];
Show[observedPlot, predictedPlot]


do you agree that the uniformity of the eigenvalues of SO($n$) only holds for $n=2$? for $n=4$ you get the double peaked function in my answer, right?

@CarloBeenakker I've updated code/diagram for $n=4$, eig dist appears uniform with 100k samples of SO(4)

there is a typo in your code; for SO(n) you are still sampling from $n=2$; if you correct that line (replace SO@2 with SO@n) you will find the double-peaked distribution $$p(\theta)=\frac{\cos 2 \theta+2}{4 \pi }.$$

@CarloBeenakker thanks for the catch, updated the code which now agrees with the formula

@CarloBeenakker btw, is there a name of the density where the angles are actually uniform? Posted question with simulations here

circular unitary ensemble? [Haar measure on $U(n)$]

@CarloBeenakker I see, that gives me uniform eigenphase distribution with complex-valued matrices. It seems there's a way to get uniform eigenphase dist with real-valued matrices by combining $n/2$ 2D rotations using Jordan Normal form, was curious if that density has a name

a small point: you remark that "Restricting to () removes the peaks at −1 and +1"; that is true for even $n$; for odd $n$ a peak a +1 remains.
